# Can I do an Oman visa change/run on a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uae, visa-runs

We have 3-month tourist visit visa to the UAE which expiring soon. Is it possible to exit via Oman and apply for another visa from there? They say it's a visa change or run. How is the process done? Also, we not from one of those countries that can get a UAE visa upon entry at the airport or border post. Below is example of the visa type.

[image]

Comment: Do you want a visa change (from tourist to residence) or to obtain a new tourist visa? Does this example show your nationality (Indian) and, if yes, don't you also need a visa to enter Oman (not eligible for e-visa or visa on arrival)?

Comment: @Dorothy I think the image was given as an example of the visa type, and is not the OP's as he says in the question.

Comment: @mkennedy although OP isn't able to enter visa free or get one on arrival. It occurred to me that would make a run to Oman difficult is OP can't enter w/o visa. So far, I've found this, that tourists who do not live in the UAE are only granted access to Oman if they have passports from EU countries, the US or Australia.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between visa change and visa run since, in 2016, [the government announced that](http://gulfnews.com/news/uae/government/no-need-to-exit-uae-to-amend-visit-visa-status-1.1648176):

> visit visa-holders no longer need to leave the country to amend the status of their visa to a residency permit, the Ministry of Interior revealed...

Such changes can be done through an [Emirates ID Authority e-form typing service](http://www.id.gov.ae/en/emirates-id-centers/typing-centers.aspx)

To make a UAE-Oman visa run, tourists in the UAE must hold passports from the specific countries listed below. For other nationalities, the alternative is a visa flight, which can be arranged through any travel agency or through FlyDubai.

You walk off the plane, into the departure terminal and straight back on again, without actually entering the destination country, even though you’ve left the UAE.

Among the many companies that offer visa service, the [First Gate Business Service](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=visa-change-oman) web site has the details.

> Following nationalities can utilize this facility for Tourist Visa renewal, Employment Visa Status Change, Family Visa Status Change.
>
> • UK
>   • Ireland
>   • USA
>   • New Zealand
>   • Australia
>   • Canada
>   • France
>   • Italy
>   • Germany
>   • Netherlands
>   • Singapore
>   • Malaysia
>   • South Korea
>   • Hong Kong SAR
>   • Belgium
>   • Luxembourg
>   • Switzerland
>   • Austria
>   • Sweden
>   • Norway
>   • Denmark
>   • Portugal
>   • Greece
>   • Finland
>   • Spain
>   • Monaco
>   • Iceland
>   • Liechtenstein
>   • Japan
>   • Brunei
>   • Poland
>   • Hungary
>   • Romania
>   • Bulgaria
>   • Lithuania
>   • Estonia
>   • Latvia
>   • Czech Republic
>   • Slovakia
>   • Slovenia
>   • Croatia
>   • Malta
>   • Cyprus
>
> • UAE Immigration will put exit stamp at UAE border. Exit Fee Dh35. Then pass through Oman check point and they will charge Dh50 for in-out stamp.
>
> • Return through UAE border and you will get Entry stamp after eye scan. From the date of entry you have 60 days time to complete [Medical](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=medical_service), [Emirates ID](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=emiratesID) and Visa Stamping.
>
> • Other nationalities can change visa by air. Visa change package is available from [Fly Dubai](http://www.flydubai.com/en/). Approximate charge Dh650. Contact any travel agency for available packages. You must have valid UAE visa in hand to use this facility.
>
> • [Y]ou can [change status](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=statuschange) without exit on payment of Dh510 (typing charge extra). Type status change form from typing centre, sign the sponsor and submit it at Immigration counter. If a company is your sponsor, you can submit status change application through [eDNRD](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=ednrd-online) online. [read more](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=oman-visa-from-uae-border)
>
> • Visa Change is allowed for Tourist and [Visit](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=visit_visa) visa holder to [Employment](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=employment_visa)/ [Residence](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=family_visa_entry)/ [Investor](http://www.visaprocess.ae/details.php?page=investor_visa) by paying Dh680+510 (typing charge extra). No need to exit UAE.
>
> Immigration Helpline: 800 5111